# Find max sum of elements in an array ( with twist)

Tags: algorithm, logic, kadanes-algorithm

Given a array with +ve and -ve integer , find the maximum sum such that you are not allowed to skip 2 contiguous elements ( i.e you have to select at least one of them to move forward).

eg :-

10 , 20 , 30, -10 , -50 , 40 , -50, -1, -3

Output : 10+20+30-10+40-1 = 89

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying to do like @IVIad Idea, No success, but the best way to attack this problem is by listing all valid lists(not to skip more than one && not to stop before n-1 element), and then adding the corresponding values and get the max. I am about to implement it, just a matter of time.

Comment: did you get the output with the answer? did you run all test cases? Could you try for this 2,-1,-10,-50,-1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a recurrence that accounts for that:

```
dp[i] = max(dp[i - 1] + a[i], <- take two consecutives
            dp[i - 2] + a[i], <- skip a[i - 1])
```

Base cases left as an exercise.

Comment: base case : 
if( input[0] > 0 && input[1] >0 )
  then dp[0] = input[0] && dp[1] = input[0] + input[1];
else
          dp[0] = input[0];
          dp[1] = max(dp[i-1] + arr[1] , dp[i-1] );
is this fine ?

Comment: @user1057741 - I wouldn't complicate things so much. dp[-1] = 0, dp[0] = a[0]. Now just  run the dp. I don't know why you compare with 0...

Answer (score 8):

This problem can be solved using Dynamic Programming approach.

Let **arr** be the given array and **opt** be the array to store the optimal solutions.
**opt[i]** is the maximum sum that can be obtained starting from element i, inclusive.

```
opt[i] = arr[i] + (some other elements after i)
```

Now to solve the problem we iterate the array **arr** backwards, each time storing the answer **opt[i]**.
Since we cannot skip 2 contiguous elements, either **element i+1** or **element i+2** has to be included
in **opt[i]**.

So for each i, `opt[i] = arr[i] + max(opt[i+1], opt[i+2])`

See this code to understand:

```
int arr[n];  // array of given numbers. array size = n.
nput(arr, n);   // input the array elements (given numbers)

int opt[n+2];   // optimal solutions. 
memset(opt, 0, sizeof(opt));    // Initially set all optimal solutions to 0.

for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    opt[i] = arr[i] + max(opt[i+1], opt[i+2]);
}

ans = max(opt[0], opt[1])   // final answer.
```

Observe that **opt** array has **n+2** elements. This is to avoid getting illegal memory access exception (memory out of bounds) when we try to access **opt[i+1]** and **opt[i+2]** for the last element **(n-1)**.

[See the working implementation of the algorithm given above](https://ideone.com/GXw5Xv)

Answer (score 2):

If you see a +ve integer add it to the sum. If you see a negative integer, then inspect the next integer pick which ever is maximum and add it to the sum.

10 , 20 , 30, -10 , -50 , 40 , -50, -1, -3

For this add 10, 20, 30, max(-10, -50), 40 max(-50, -1) and since there is no element next to -3 discard it.

The last element will go to sum if it was +ve.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:



I think this algorithm will help.


1. Create a method which gives output the maximum sum of particular user input array say T[n], where n denotes the total no. of elements.

2. Now this method will keep on adding array elements till they are positive. As we want to maximize the sum and there is no point in dropping positive elements behind.

3. As soon as our method encounters a negative element, it will transfer all consecutive negative elements to another method which create a new array say N[i] such that this array will contain all the consecutive negative elements that we encountered in T[n] and returns N[i]'s max output.

In this way our main method is not affected and its keep on adding positive elements and whenever it encounters negative element, it instead of adding their real values adds the net max output of that consecutive array of negative elements.


for example: T[n] = 29,34,55,-6,-5,-4,6,43,-8,-9,-4,-3,2,78   //here n=14


Main Method Working:


29+34+55+(sends data & gets value from Secondary method of array [-6,-5,-4])+6+43+(sends data & gets value from Secondary method of array [-8,-9,-4,-3])+2+78

Process Terminates with max output.


Secondary Method Working:

{


N[i] = gets array from Main method or itself as and when required.
This is basically a recursive method.

say N[i] has elements like N1, N2, N3, N4, etc.


for i>=3:

Now choice goes like this.

1. If we take N1 then we can recurse the left off array i.e. N[i-1] which has all elements except N1 in same order. Such that the net max output will be 

N1+(sends data & gets value from Secondary method of array N[i-1] recursively)

2. If we doesn't take N1, then we cannot skip N2. So, Now algorithm is like 1st choice but starting with N2. So max output in this case will be

N2+(sends data & gets value from Secondary method of array N[i-2] recursively).
Here N[i-2] is an array containing all N[i] elements except N1 & N2 in same order.

Termination: When we are left with the array of size one ( for N[i-2] ) then we have to choose that particular value as no option.

The recursions will finally yield the max outputs and we have to finally choose the output of that choice which is more.
and redirect the max output to wherever required.


for i=2:

we have to choose the value which is bigger


for i=1:

We can surely skip that value.

So max output in this case will be 0.


}

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer will help to you.

Given array:

```
Given:- 10 20 30 -10 -50 40 -50 -1 -3

Array1:-10 30 60  50  10 90  40 89 86

Array2:-10  20 50  40  0  80  30 79 76
```

Take the max value of `array1[n-1],array1[n],array2[n-1],array2[n] i.e 89(array1[n-1])`

Algorithm:-

1. For the array1 value assign a`rray1[0]=a[0],array1=a[0]+a[1]`   and `array2[0]=a[0],array2[1]=a[1]`.
2. calculate the array1 value from 2 to n is max of sum of `array1[i-1]+a[i]` or `array1[i-2]+a[i]`.

   ```
   for loop from 2 to n{    
       array1[i]=max(array1[i-1]+a[i],array1[i-2]+a[i]);

   }
   ```
3. similarly for array2 value from 2 to n is max of sum of `array2[i-1]+a[i]` or `array2[i-2]+a[i].`

   ```
   for loop from 2 to n{    
    array2[i]=max(array2[i-1]+a[i],array2[i-2]+a[i]);    
   }
   ```
4. Finally find the max value of `array1[n-1],array[n],array2[n-1],array2[n]`;

   ```
      int max(int a,int b){      
      return a>b?a:b;    
      }

      int main(){    
      int a[]={10,20,30,-10,-50,40,-50,-1,-3};    
      int i,n,max_sum;    
      n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);    
      int array1[n],array2[n];    
      array1[0]=a[0];    
      array1[1]=a[0]+a[1];    
      array2[0]=a[0];    
       array2[1]=a[1];    

       for loop from 2 to n{    
       array1[i]=max(array1[i-1]+a[i],array1[i-2]+a[i]);    
       array2[i]=max(array2[i-1]+a[i],array2[i-2]+a[i]);

       }    
          --i;

       max_sum=max(array1[i],array1[i-1]);    
       max_sum=max(max_sum,array2[i-1]);    
       max_sum=max(max_sum,array2[i]);    

        printf("The max_sum is %d",max_sum);    
         return 0;    
       }
   ```

Ans: The max_sum is 89

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void countSum(int[] a) {
        int count = 0;
        int skip = 0;
        int newCount = 0;

        if(a.length==1)
        {
            count = a[0];
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i:a)
            {
                newCount = count + i;
                if(newCount>=skip)
                {
                    count = newCount;
                    skip = newCount;
                }
                else
                {
                    count = skip;
                    skip = newCount;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain how you solved the problem asked by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Let the array be of size N, indexed as 1...N

Let f(n) be the function, that provides the answer for max sum of sub array (1...n), such that no two left over elements are consecutive.

```
 f(n) = max (a[n-1] + f(n-2), a(n) + f(n-1))
```

In first option, which is - {a[n-1] + f(n-2)}, we are leaving the last element, and due to condition given in question selecting the second last element.

In the second option, which is - {a(n) + f(n-1)} we are selecting the last element of the subarray, so we have an option to select/deselect the second last element.

Now starting from the base case :

```
f(0) = 0   [Subarray (1..0) doesn't exist]

f(1) = (a[1] > 0 ? a[1] : 0);    [Subarray (1..1)]

f(2) = max( a(2) + 0, a[1] + f(1))   [Choosing atleast one of them]
```

Moving forward we can calculate any f(n), where n = 1...N, and store them to calculate next results. And yes, obviously, the case f(N) will give us the answer.

```
Time complexity o(n)
Space complexity o(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

n = arr.length().
Append a 0 at the end of the array to handle boundary case.
ans: int array of size n+1.
ans[i] will store the answer for array a[0...i] which includes a[i] in the answer sum.
Now,

```
ans[0] = a[0]
ans[1] = max(a[1], a[1] + ans[0])
for i in [2,n-1]: 
   ans[i] = max(ans[i-1] , ans[i-2]) + a[i]
```

Final answer would be a[n]

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to avoid using Dynamic Programming

- To find the maximum sum, first, you've to add all the positive
  numbers.
- We'll be skipping only negative elements. Since we're not
  allowed to skip 2 contiguous elements, we will put all **contiguous**
  negative elements in a temp array, and can figure out the maximum sum
  of alternate elements using sum_odd_even function as defined below.
- Then we can add the maximum of all such temp arrays to our sum of all
  positive numbers. And the final sum will give us the desired output.

Code:

```
def sum_odd_even(arr):
    sum1 = sum2 = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if i%2 == 0:
            sum1 += arr[i]
        else:
            sum2 += arr[i]
    return max(sum1,sum2)

input = [10, 20, 30, -10, -50, 40, -50, -1, -3]
result = 0
temp = []
for i in range(len(input)):
    if input[i] > 0:
        result += input[i]
    if input[i] < 0 and i != len(input)-1:
        temp.append(input[i])
    elif input[i] < 0:
        temp.append(input[i])
        result += sum_odd_even(temp)
        temp = []
    else:
        result += sum_odd_even(temp)
        temp = []

print result
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution:  Skip with twist :). Just skip the smallest number in i & i+1 if consecutive -ve. Have if conditions to check that till n-2 elements and check for the last element in the end.

```
int getMaxSum(int[] a) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= a.length-2; i++) {
        if (a[i]>0){
            sum +=a[i];
            continue;
        } else if (a[i+1] > 0){
            i++;
            continue;
        } else {
            sum += Math.max(a[i],a[i+1]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (a[a.length-1] > 0){
        sum+=a[a.length-1];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for your answer. Rather than just posting a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the issue is you solved and how you solved it? This will help people who find this question in the future to better understand the issue and how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

The correct recurrence is as follow:

```
dp[i] = max(dp[i - 1] + a[i], dp[i - 2] + a[i - 1])
```

The first case is the one we pick the i-th element. The second case is the one we skip the i-th element. In the second case, we must pick the (i-1)th element.

The problem of IVlad's answer is that it always pick i-th element, which can lead to incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0):

This question can be solved using include,exclude approach.

For first element, `include = arr[0], exclude = 0`.

For rest of the elements:

```
nextInclude = arr[i]+max(include, exclude)

nextExclude = include 

include = nextInclude

exclude = nextExclude
```

Finally, `ans = Math.max(include,exclude)`.

Similar questions can be referred at (Not the same)=> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VT4bZV24QNo&t=675s&ab_channel=Pepcoding.